# Airflow Dataflow Job status error even though Dataflowtemplate run successful

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am orchestrating Dataflow Template job via Composer and using   `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator` and `DataflowJobStatusSensor` for  running the job. I am getting following error with sensor operator
Failure log of `DataflowJobStatusSensor`

```
    job_status = job["currentState"]
KeyError: 'currentState'

Error 
Dataflow Template job runs successfully but DataflowJobStatusSensor fails always with  the error . I have attached screenshot of the whole orchestration
[2022-02-11 04:18:11,057] {dataflow.py:100} INFO - Waiting for job  to be in one of the states: JOB_STATE_DONE.
[2022-02-11 04:18:11,109] {credentials_provider.py:300} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-02-11 04:18:11,776] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - 'currentState'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Code

```
wait_for_job = DataflowJobStatusSensor(
        task_id="wait_for_job",
        job_id="{{task_instance.xcom_pull('start_x_job')['dataflow_job_id']}}",
        expected_statuses={DataflowJobStatus.JOB_STATE_DONE},
        location=gce_region
    )
```

Xcom value -

```
return_value

{"id": "2022-02-12_02_35_39-14489165686319399318", "projectId": "xx38", "name": "start-x-job-0b4921", "type": "JOB_TYPE_BATCH", "currentStateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", "createTime": "2022-02-12T10:35:40.423475Z", "location": "us-xxx", "startTime": "2022-02-12T10:35:40.423475Z"}
```

Any clue why I am getting the Error - currentstate

Thanks

Comment: First I think you will have to check the integrity of you airflow installed. Have you manage to run one of the examples provided on [example_dataflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6ef44b6a507a8e8d5f41a6731a0773046623d171/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataflow.py) for this kind of operators??. Also have you manage to print `job` info without specifying `[currentState]`

Comment: Thanks Betjens I will try it out. The airflow version we are currently on is 1.01 old version

Comment: wow, your version its too old (latest is 2.2.3). well on that case I think the airflow operators are also different. Check the official documentation for your version I couldn't find version 1.01 but documentation for [1.10.1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/index.html) and the usage of the [operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/howto/operator.html?highlight=operators#google-cloud-platform-operators). Also check the connection for it.

Comment: Could you confirm your airflow version?

Comment: Hi Betjens - we currently use airflow version 1.10.15

Answer (score 0):

After checking documentation for version [1.10.15](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/backport-providers.html), it gives you the option to run airflow providers (from version 2.0.*) on airflow 1.0. So you shouldn't haver issues, as described in my comments you should be able to run [example_dataflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6ef44b6a507a8e8d5f41a6731a0773046623d171/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataflow.py) although you might need to update the code to reflect your version.

For what I see from your error message, have you also check your credentials as described on [Google Cloud Connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) page. Use the example or a small dag run using the operators to test your connection. You can find video-guides like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1902&v=wAyu5BN3VpY&feature=youtu.be). Remember that the credentials must be within reach of your airflow application.

Also, If you are using google-dataflow-composer you should be able to setup your credentials as show on [DataflowTemplateOperator Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator#dataflowtemplateoperator_configuration).

As a final note, if you find messy to move forward with airflow migration and latest updates, your best approach is to use [kubernetes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/kubernetes.html) Operator. In the short term, this will allow to create image with latest updates and you only have to pass credential info to the image and  you will be able to update your docker image to the latest and it will still working regardless of the version of airflow that you are using. It's a short term solution, still you should consider migrating to 2.0.*.

Comment: Hello, `recyclinguy`. Were you able to make it work?